# How to add item at zero position in spinner in hashmap?

Tags: android, hashmap, spinner

I am using below code to populate spinner with hashmap from SQL. Now I want to add hardcoded "select" at zero position but I failed. I used resultListMachineClientID .add() but it is not allow me to add value. How can I achieve this ?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultListMachineClientID = new ArrayList<>();

class async_fillClientId extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            showDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            resultListMachineClientID.clear();
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {

                    getActivity().getParent().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    String query = "exec App_Combo_ClientDetail";
                    ResultSet rs = dbHelp.executeRS(query);
                    try {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hashstate = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hashstate.put(TAG_ID_machineClientId, rs.getString("nClientID"));
                            hashstate.put(TAG_Name_machineClientName, rs.getString("cClientName"));
                            resultListMachineClientID.add(hashstate);
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultClientID;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {

            try {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapterClientID = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), resultListMachineClientID, R.layout.activity_showspinner_client_id, new String[]{TAG_ID_machineClientId, TAG_Name_machineClientName}, new int[]{R.id.nSerialClientID, R.id.cCodeClientNAme});
                spnClientID.setAdapter(adapterClientID);
                hideDialog();

                spnClientID.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                               int pos, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        TextView txtid1 = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.nSerialClientID);

                        nClintID = txtid1.getText().toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            super.onPostExecute(result1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try.. `resultListMachineClientID .add(new HashMap<"select",null>)`

Comment: sourabh this is giving me expression error.

Comment: can you show me.. how you did?

Comment: while (rs.next()) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hashstate = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hashstate.put(TAG_ID_machineClientId, rs.getString("nClientID"));
                            hashstate.put(TAG_Name_machineClientName, rs.getString("cClientName"));
                            resultListMachineClientID .add(new HashMap<"select",null>);
                            resultListMachineClientID.add(hashstate);
                        }

Comment: use `resultListMachineClientID .add(new HashMap<"select","select">())`

and put it before loop.

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: show my answer.

Comment: Sorry sourabh not working.

Answer (score 0):

Before it you add

```
hashstate.put(TAG_Name_machineClientName, "Select Value");
```

After that put server data

```
 String query = "exec App_Combo_ClientDetail";
                    ResultSet rs = dbHelp.executeRS(query);
                    try {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hashstate = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hashstate.put(TAG_ID_machineClientId, rs.getString("nClientID"));
                            hashstate.put(TAG_Name_machineClientName, rs.getString("cClientName"));
                            resultListMachineClientID.add(hashstate);
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: I have done this but it is not working. while (rs.next()) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hashstate = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hashstate.put(TAG_ID_machineClientId, rs.getString("nClientID"));
                            hashstate.put(TAG_Name_machineClientName, rs.getString("cClientName"));
                            hashstate.put(TAG_Name_machineClientName, "Select Value");
                            resultListMachineClientID.add(hashstate);

Comment: please give me json response --and what is your requirement?? i will do

Comment: my above code is working like a charm in my ques. I just want to add "select" at first in spinner hardcoded.

Comment: yes i want to say before put value in hashmap ..put hardcode value put after that  server response put in hashmap ..than default first value you see select vale

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            resultListMachineClientID.clear();
// add these lines
                HashMap select= new HashMap();
                select.put("select","select");
                resultListMachineClientID .add(select);
//
```

Comment: after adding this it is showing blank value at first.